# Reload a UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to implement a favorite-marker feature. I realized that with a Font Awesome Star.

Now I try to reload the UIBarButtonItem after a click, because the Star has to be full or empty (depending on the user's like or not).
I don't find any option to do that :(

My button declaration:

```
 markedButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "onMarkedTap:")
    if questionWithIdIsMarked(detailItem2!){
        markedButton.setFAIcon(FAType.FAStar, iconSize: 25)
    }else{
        markedButton.setFAIcon(FAType.FAStarO, iconSize: 25)
    }
    let navButtons = [shuffleBtn, markedButton]
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(navButtons, animated: true)
```

It tried to `sender.view?.reloadInputViews()` in the `onMarkedTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer` first but that also didn't work. Problem is that the UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from UIView so it's not so easy to reload it.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Show what you tried.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded some more stuff :)

Comment: I am kind of confused ? are you trying to add a UITabBarItem once it is clicked some code should ran

Comment: No I added a UIBarButtonItem (called markedButton) to my navigation bar. Depending if the question is already marked it has to look like filled star or like an empty one.

If you click on the markedButton, it should change. If it was marked before, it should now be unmarked and the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare two normal buttons like :

```
var btnFavourite:UIButton!
var btnShuffle:UIButton!
```

Then in `viewDidLoad()`, write following code

```
self.btnFavourite = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
self.btnFavourite.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
self.btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "blank_star.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "fill_star.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
self.btnFavourite.addTarget(self, action: "favourite:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.btnShuffle = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
self.btnShuffle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
self.btnShuffle.setImage(UIImage(named: "shuffle.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.btnShuffle.addTarget(self, action: "shuffle:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

let barButtons = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnFavourite), UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnShuffle)]
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barButtons
```

And implement methods for both buttons as below

```
@IBAction func favourite(sender:UIButton) {

    if self.btnFavourite.selected == true {

        self.btnFavourite.selected = false
    }
    else {

        self.btnFavourite.selected = true
    }
}

@IBAction func shuffle(sender:UIButton) {

    // your code
}
```

Comment: Sir, you are really awesome. Works fine with some small adjustments. Thank you very much!